# Why can't I assign drive letters in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drive-letter

My Google-fu has failed me.

I've found info around the net for assigning and rearranging drive letters, but this problem is different.

I have a laptop that shows the C: drive just fine. However, the DVD drive and anything else that you hook up to it doesn't get a drive letter. And when you try to assign one manually, it doesn't give you an error, it just doesn't assign the letter to the drive.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Any ideas or even pointing me in a correct general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When did the problem start? Any new software installed just before it did start?

Comment: Not sure. I noticed it when I got a T-Mobile Internet Stick and when I plugged it in, it didn't give me the option to install the software like it usually does.

But the weird thing is that everything shows up fine in Drive Management. Even the DVD drive shows up there, but it doesn't get a drive letter or shows up in Explorer.

Comment: Sounds like the usb controller drivers have gone wonky, use device manager to uninstall everything under Universal Serial Bus Controllers, when done uninstalling Do Not reboot, but right click on any device and select scan for hardware changes, the devices and drivers should be reinstalled, then reboot and try a usb drive.

Comment: You can also try this before reinstalling USB controllers, open an elevated command prompt and type the following commands, hitting enter for each one...diskpart <enter>...automount enable <enter>

Comment: I tried diskpart => automount enable and it completed successfully. But that didn't fix my problem.

New info, when I go to Devices & Printers, my T-Mobile stick shows up, but it says there are errors. And the troubleshooter can't help (ever).

Comment: I was digging around and found this under Properties in Devices & Printers. Device Function Summary: Manufacturer: HUAWEI, Location: on UMBus Enumerator, Device status: The device cannot start (Code 10).

Comment: Moab, I took your suggestions and removed everything under Universal Serial Bus Controllers and rescanned hardware. Everything came back fine. Inserted the Tmobile Stick and it went through it's hoopla and finally it finished finding things. Only thing left is WPD Filesystem Volume Driver. Has the error "Device cannot start (Code 10).

Comment: Try a couple of reboots.

Comment: If no joy, see the post by Paul H NJ on this page.....http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/itprovistahardware/thread/24374678-e65d-40fd-9581-62b09c8feeb8

Comment: Code 10 errors....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943104

Comment: No luck with reboots. :P And the post at Technet gave me hope, but ultimately, that failed, too. And the kb article said it found errors when I ran the FixIt but failed to fix them. Any other suggestions before I reinstall the OS?

Comment: When did you notice this problem starting, after installing software?

Comment: When I inserted the Tmobile Stick it didn't show up. That's when I started investigating. It didn't show in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Open Windows System restore, see what restore point are listed, maybe it will refresh your memory on what was installed recently and possibly caused this.

Comment: Unfortunately, system restore wasn't turned on. Otherwise I would have just restored to a previous point (hopefully one without this problem). But alas, it looks like a reinstall of Windows 7 is all that's left. I don't want to format this thing.

Comment: There is a way to do a Repair install, but you need the correct media, the W7 DVD also needs to be the same Service Pack level as the installation you are repairing...http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/how-to-do-a-repair-install-to-fix-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys and gals! I'm going to try out the repair install. If that doesn't work. I dunno. Maybe try pulling the drivers from another machine running win7? Think that might work?

Comment: I don't think drivers are going to fix it, its a registry problem.

Comment: Well, the inevitable, I suppose. Format and reinstall using recovery media. Yay. If anyone finds out how to repair the WPD Volume Driver or whatever it's called, please put it in the comments! It would greatly help a number of internet citizens.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like drive letters are hidden for you, can you use [DriveLetterView](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/265/1/Customize-the-drive-letter-display-in-Windows-Vista.html) and make sure they are shown?

If this doesn't work; please update your post and describe what you see and do, perhaps with screenshots.

Comment: I couldn't use the utility on the page. When I try to open it, I get the error "Unsupported Compression Method."

Comment: Here are some screens I grabbed. 1) http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/4981/mycomputerr.png 2) http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2799/computermanagement.png 3) http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/363/tryingtoassignletter.png 4) http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/5702/afterdriveletterassign.png

This shows My Computer, Computer Management, Trying to assign a drive letter, and afterwards.